# For $p$ prime and $\omega = {e^{\frac{{2\pi i}}{p}}}$, show that $\omega \left( {1 - {\omega ^{k - 1}}} \right)$ divides p

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In Number fields, Marcus, problem 17 on page 9 reduces to the following:

Show that $\omega \left( {1 - {\omega ^{k - 1}}} \right)|p$ for $k \geqslant 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}\left[ \omega  \right]$, where $\omega  = {e^{\frac{{2\pi i}}{p}}}$ and $p$ is a prime integer. The hint says to use $\prod\limits_{k = 1}^{p - 1} {\left( {1 - {\omega ^k}} \right)}  = p$, which is useful to see that $1 - \omega |p$, but I can't see how to use this to get the divisibility above.

I have proven that $\prod\limits_{k = 1}^{p - 1} {\left( {x - {\omega ^k}} \right)}  = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{p - 1} {{x^i}} $ and ${x^p} + 1 = \prod\limits_{k = 0}^{p - 1} {\left( {x + {\omega ^k}} \right)} $, substituting $x = 1$ in the first equality gives $\prod\limits_{k = 1}^{p - 1} {\left( {1 - {\omega ^k}} \right)}  = p$ and I'm not sure if the second equality is useful at all.

Unnecessary context added for completeness, here's the problem and what I've done thus far:

17. Suppose that $\mathbb{Z}\left[ \omega  \right]$ is a unique factorization domain and that $\pi $ is irreducible such that $\pi |x + \omega y$. Show that $\pi $ does not divide any of the other factors in the equation $\prod\limits_{k = 0}^{p - 1} {\left( {x + y{\omega ^k}} \right)}  = {z^p}$ by showing that if it did, it would divide both $z$ and $yp$.

My solution up to this point: If it divides at least one other factor then it divides their difference, so either $\pi |y\left( {1 - \omega } \right),1 - \omega |yp \Rightarrow \pi |yp$ or $\pi |y\omega \left( {1 - {\omega ^{k - 1}}} \right)$. If $\omega \left( {1 - {\omega ^{k - 1}}} \right)|p$, we're practically done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p = {\omega ^p}p = {\omega ^p}\prod\limits_{k = 1}^{p - 1} {(1 - {\omega ^k})}  = \omega\cdot\prod\limits_{k = 2}^p {\omega (1 - {\omega ^{k - 1}})} $.